# Firefox cli save page

Tags: firefox

It's possible to save page page with Firefox CLI?

Something like:

```
firefox -new-tab http://google.com -save-page /path/
```

Comment: Any particular reason to use `firefox`? there are other CLI alternatives that are great for saving web pages. Even whole sites.

Comment: Any alternatives are welcome, single requirement they must available on Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any really simple way to do this. You might consider looking into a browser automation tool like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). Alternatively, a more general automation tool like [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) might be workable as well (this is actually likely to be easier than using Selenium, depending on exactly what you want to do).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [list of Firefox command line arguments](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments), there is no such thing.

There is a command line tool called [**wget**](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/) (link is for Windows version, I suppose you are using Windows? If not, it's already included in every Linux distribution) which was made for exactly this purpose. Run it like this:

```
wget.exe -P /path http://google.com
```

Comment: `wget` cannot execute javascript

Comment: I didn't know that was a requirement, I don't know then.